# MySQL select subquery with sum, limit and order

Tags: mysql, scope, subquery, sql-order-by, limit

I need to select sum of top 3 scores from each team from all disciplines. Better score = more points. So I can show general scores from the tournament. I try to run sth. like this:

```
SELECT t.name, 
  (SELECT SUM(points) FROM (SELECT points
    FROM scores
    WHERE team = t.id
    ORDER BY points DESC
    LIMIT 3) points) sum
  FROM teams t
```

But i get error:

```
Unknown column 't.id' in 'where clause'
```

Here's link to schema and data:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecc66b/20

Please help me. I'm sure this query would work in MsSQL, but I'm forced to use MySQL

Comment: If my memory serves me right you can only acces the outer query 1 level deep and you're using it on one level deeper hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is acces a value from a column from the outer query that is the outer query from your current query.

Besides that being the problem could you not simply use the `SUM()` function inside the second subquery, that way there is no need for the first subquery.

Take a look at your modified [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecc66b/43)

Also some more information on the problem can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/correlated-subqueries.html)

Comment: Sorry but `SUM` is not compatible with limit as we can expect. Database engine will first sum all of the results that meets with `WHERE` requirements, Output one row (sum of all elements) and after that it will apply `LIMIT 3` to this one row.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that one, sorry consider this a bad answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the top 3 rank per group (or top N per group, in general) is a very tricky problem in MySQL, which does not have any built-in support for analytic functions like `ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK`, or `DENSE_RANK`.  As you may have detected in your comment about SQL Server, this problem would be much easier to handle in another database, like SQL Server, which supports analytic functions.

One option in MySQL is to simulate the analytic functions using session variables.  In the case of your data set, we might want to simulate the dense rank.  Consider the following query:

```
SET @dr = 0;
SET @points = NULL;
SET @team = NULL;

SELECT
    s.dr,
    s.points,
    t.name AS team_name,
    d.name AS discipline_name
FROM
(
    SELECT
        @dr:=CASE WHEN @team = team AND @points <> points THEN @dr + 1
                  WHEN @team = team AND @points = points THEN @dr
                  ELSE 1 END AS dr,
        @points:=points AS points,
        @team:=team AS team,
        discipline
    FROM scores s
    ORDER BY
        s.team,
        s.points DESC
) s
INNER JOIN teams t
    ON s.team = t.id
INNER JOIN disciplines d
    ON s.discipline = d.id
WHERE s.dr <= 3
ORDER BY
    s.team,
    s.points DESC;
```

**Output:**

[image]

Note carefully in the output above that there is a tie for third place within the dogs team, between the running and flying disciplines.  It is good that your data contains such a tie, because this is an edge case worth not looking over.  In fact, this is why I chose to simulate the dense rank, rather than the row number, the latter might arbitrarily choose one of the two third place records to report.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester




## SQLFiddle

 (your original Fiddle updated)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to consider the ex aequo scores. This is the code that did what I expect.

```
SET @dr = 0;
SET @points = NULL;
SET @team = NULL;

SELECT
    sum(s.points) points_total,
    t.name AS team_name
FROM
(
    SELECT
        @dr:=CASE WHEN @team = team THEN @dr + 1 ELSE 1 END AS dr,
        @points:=points AS points,
        @team:=team AS team,
        discipline
    FROM scores s
    ORDER BY
        s.team,
        s.points DESC
) s
INNER JOIN teams t
    ON s.team = t.id
INNER JOIN disciplines d
    ON s.discipline = d.id
WHERE s.dr <= 3
GROUP BY 
  t.name
ORDER BY
    1 DESC;
```

Thank you @Tim Biegeleisen for showing the path.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Now I'm confused about your requirements.  What does `select sum of top 3 scores from each team from all disciplines` actually mean?

Comment: For general score there are taken three best (more points) result for each team (doesn't matter in which discipline). So I need to order scores of each team DESCending, take 3 top of them, sum it up and this is the team general result.